# HTML: Encapsulate content in a box

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS programming (more comfortable with Python/C++), and I'm having some difficulty trying to accomplish a relatively simple task:

I basically want a box that encapsulates a number of things. I need a small image accompanied by two chunks of text, the first aligned left with the image and the second aligned right with the box. These should all by horizontally padded within the line in the box.

I then want a larger image below that first line, which is still in the box but is expanded to fit the width of the box. I then want some lines of text below that for a caption.

Because I need many of these "boxes," my instinct in Python would be to create a class object that I can reuse over and over. I'm having difficulty translating this concept to HTML/CSS, however.

Thus far, I have something like the following:

```css
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid black ;
    padding: 25px
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-left: 55px;
}

.img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-top: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="boxed">
        <span class="right">mm/dd/yy</span>
        <img src="/files/img_icon.jpg" alt="some_icon" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <span class="left"><b>some name</b></span>
        <span class ="img"><img src="/files/sample_img.jpg" alt="bigger_img (should be inside box)" max-width: 100%></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

But it's not running how I intend it to. Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: If it's about positioning, I would suggest you to take a look at flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="boxed">
        <div class="left">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/25" alt="some_icon" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <span><b>some name</b></span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
             <span>mm/dd/yy</span>
        </div>

        <div class ="img">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="bigger_img (should be inside box)" max-width: 100%></span>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid black ;
    padding: 25px
}

.right {
    float: right;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.img {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-top: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You could also use flex-box but it isn't supported in all browsers yet and can be a little more confusing when first starting out. I put the date inside its own span within a box so that if you wanted to add other things to the right side you could just put them within the "right" classed box.